# Estimation question

Tags: estimation

Suppose I want to estimate the area of a circle by getting 10 measurements of its diameter. I assume that the measurements are Normal (D,1). I want to get an estimate of the area, A using the method of moments. My question is, will this work if I used the method of moments to get an estimate for D and just get an estimate of A based on my estimate of D or should I first find the distribution of A and use the method of moments for A? Thanks.

Comment: Also as a followup question. If my MLE for D is unbiased for D, does that mean that my estimate for A, which is computed from the estimate of D is also unbiased for A? Thanks.

Comment: Expectation is a linear operator. That means the general answer to your question is no, an unbiased estimator for $D$ does not mean the estimate of $A$ computed from it will be unbiased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you try the first method and use the method of moments to estimate $D.$  Let $\bar x$ be the average of your 10 measurements. Since your population is normal, $\bar x \sim \mathrm{N} \left( D,\frac{1}{10} \right)$

Then since for any random variable with finite variance the second moment is given by $E[X^2] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2,$ we have $$E \left[ {\bar x}^2 \right]=\frac{1}{10}+D^2$$

In terms of the diameter $d$, the area of a circle is $$A = \frac{\pi d^2}{4}$$ If we let $\hat A_1$ be the estimate of the area using your first method, its expectation will be $$E \left[ \hat A_1 \right] =\left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right) \left( \frac{1}{10} + D^2 \right)=\frac{\pi D^2}{4}+\frac{\pi}{40}$$

So there is a bias of $\frac{\pi}{40}$ using this approach. Can you take it from here?